# ACF frontend form wordpress category not working

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using a acf frontend form to create posts. All the fields are working but on frontend I want a field that should automatically asiign category at backend to the post.

I have custom post type name "person".

For adding the post from frontend form, here is the code

```
    // Create a new post
$post = array(
    'post_status'  => 'draft' ,
    'post_title'  => $_POST['fields']['field_53c8f0941cec0'] ,
    'post_category'  =>  array(43,47) ,
    'post_type'  => 'person' ,
    'submit_value'  => 'Submit' ,
);  

// insert the post
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );
```

.
 The custom taxonomy name for my "person" custom post type is "person_type" 
All the fields get saved but category does not gets saved at backend.

ANy help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be pretty straight
Use

```
'tax_input'      => array( 'CUSTOM_TAXONOMY_NAME' => array( COMMA SEPARTED VALUES OF TERMS)),
```

Example

```
  $post = array(
        'post_status'  => 'Pending' ,
        'post_title'  => $new_title ,
        'post_type'  => 'products' ,
        'tax_input'      => array( 'products_type' => array( 11,33)),
        'post_content' => $contentBlock,
        'submit_value'  => 'Submit' ,
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', 'your custom term slug', 'your custom taxonomy' );

$term_id = $term->term_id;

'tax_input' => array( 'your taxonomy' => $term_id )
```

this may help